# Нет графического окна программы при запуске exe

Tags: python, gui, консоль, pycharm, pyinstaller

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]Созданный в pyinstaller exe-шник при запуске выводит только консоль и сразу закрывает ее при этом не открывая графическое окно(Form формировал в QT Designer).

- PyCharm нормально выходит графическое окно.
- файл 1.ui находится в одной папке с главным скриптом main.py

ps pyinstaller не ругался, все сформировал, но окно Gui не выходит, только консоль.

Comment: пожалуйста, предоставьте [mcve] и покажите формат запуска строки `pyinstaller`

Comment: C:\Users\Almaz\PycharmProjects\MetaTrader5>pyinstaller main.py

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Есть пара нюансов с PyQt. Нужно еще в path указать директорию к pyqt.
Попробуйте создать exe командой

```bsh
pyinstaller --noupx --onefile --noconsole --path PATH_TO_VENV\Lib\site-packages\PyQt5\Qt\bin script.py
```

`PATH_TO_VENV` соответственно ваш путь к виртуальному окружению.
`script.py` соответственное Ваш файл со скриптом.

Если вы собираете проект в виртуальном окружении то и pyinstaller должен быть в этом же окружении

Comment: Подскажите пожалуйста, где можно ознакомиться с нюансами, о которых вы пишите.

Comment: @S. Nick Собственно про path и одно окружение и есть все нюансы ). Где именно уже не вспомню давно было. Тоже маялся с неправильным отображением.

Answer (score 0):

разобрался вроде как, оказывается в папке с exe-ником должен быть еще файл
.ui(то биш сама форма) :) ... а я то думал в файле exe сама форма тоже как бы есть при компиляции pyinstaller-a по идее должно быть предусмотрено